# Writing into multiple talend excel sheet performance issue

Tags: excel, talend

I am working on an ETL project using Talend. I am generating reports file to be sent automatically by mail to an audience. Most of these files are excel files. I have succeeded in generating all the reports with just single sheets.

My problem is that the jobs to generate the other excel report files having more than one sheet do not execute to completion due to out of memory error. Some of these files are 6MB in size. I have increased the memory parameters in Talend but I keep having this issue.

Is there a way to write data into the different sheets of an excel file in Talend in a way as to minimize memory consumption?

Comment: Instead of writing in the excel file at once, can you do it under several iterations (open the file, new sheet at each iteration) to avoid the error?

Comment: @hathija that's what I did. I extracted the data from the first sheet, created the file and sheet then write to the file. Then extracted that data for the other sheets and appended the sheets and write into the respective sheets. This job worked well last week but since I had to include some data for last week this week the job keeps running out of memory.